# In Angular2, how to dynamically select properties based on the similar part of the key in an ngFor loop?

Tags: html, angular

I have in a component an array of objects like this:

```
fields = [
  { abcOptions: [ ... ], abcConfigs: [ ... ] },
  { defOptions: [ ... ], defConfigs: [ ... ] },
  { xyzOptions: [ ... ], xyzConfigs: [ ... ] }
]
```

In the html, I want to render all these objects to make fields for input. So something like this, and I could just do like this 3 times for the three objects above:

```
<ng2-selectize [options]="abcOptions" [config]="abcConfigs"></ng2-selectize>
```

However, to have leaner codes, I want to use `ngFor` for this task. Moreover, the actual array has like 10 objects, and I don't want to repeat the same code 10 times.

So I would like to attempt something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <ng2-selectize [options]="<!--option key here-->" [config]="<!--config key here-->"></ng2-selectize>
</div>
```

Problem is I'm not sure how to dynamically insert the properties into the code for each iteration, since the keys are different in names. But they have some last letters that are the same, I guess there could be a way to do this. Like `[options]="field[*Options]"` maybe or something, I don't really know the syntax. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to retrieve the array of values. This solution assumes that options is always at index `0` and config is always at index `1` in any given `field` object:

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <ng2-selectize [options]="getOptions(field)" [config]="getConfig(field)"></ng2-selectize>
  <br />
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
getOptions(field: any): any[] {
  return field[Object.keys(field)[0]];
}

getConfig(field: any): any[] {
  return field[Object.keys(field)[1]];
}
```

Here is the [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcyxg6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) in action.

I would however recommend, **if possible**, to just consistent property names to avoid needing any kind of methods to extract the values. You could perhaps add an additional property to each `field` object to specify and utilize the `abc`/`xyz` identifies/groupings. With that property you could sort/map/reduce as much as possible needed. That way you could just do something like:

```
fields = [
  { id: 'abc', options: [ ... ], configs: [ ... ] }
];

<div *ngFor="let field of fields">
  <ng2-selectize [options]="field.options" [config]="field.configs"></ng2-selectize>
</div>
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have this method in your component,

```
getFromFields(field: any, type: string) {
 const value = Object.keys(field).find((key) => (new RegExp(type + '$')).test(key));
 if (value) {
  return field[value];
 }
}
```

Use it in the template like this,

```
<ng2-selectize [options]="getFromFields(field, 'Options')" [config]="getFromFields(field, 'Configs')"></ng2-selectize>
```

Comment: Hi. How would this be different from spelling out the key names at the first place? If I still have to pass something specific like 'abc' into the parameter, I cannot iterate over all objects.

Comment: Sorry, I was updating in a hurry and missed your `<div *ngFor...>` section. I have updated my answer. In my updated answer, the index of the properties inside each `field` object doesn't matter. It will look for a property name that has a pattern `*` (whatever, like 'abc') followed by the second argument `type` in it. If present, it will return that value to be passed on to the template's `@Input()` property.